# Kafka Streams combinations of message

Tags: java, apache-kafka, real-time, apache-kafka-streams

I have messages in topic (compact topic):

```
{id: 1, groupId: 1}
{id: 2, groupId: 1}
{id: 3, groupId: 1}
{id: 4, groupId: 2}
```

I want grouped messages by `groupId` and then get all possible combinations in each group. For example for `groupId=1` combinations:
`id:1-id:2`, `id:1-id:3`, `id:2-id:3`.

How can I do this?

Maybe self-join streams?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `map` operator to move the groupId over to the record key, then `groupByKey`

Otherwise, use `aggregate` operator and reduce by the value's groupId